# issue in sql join query formation

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

I have two tables Say A and B. A is master table and B is child table, from which I need values as below.

```
select A.Id, A.Name, B.Path from A,B where A.Id=B.Id
```

Now, I want to add column of 3rd table which is child of table 'B', say C i.e. C.File.

The value of C.File will be null if C.SubId=B.SubId is false else will return value when condition becomes true.

Comment: Well, you don't have a `FROM`, you might want to add that to your query

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: @SqlZim there's not even an old-style join in the query

Comment: @Lamak I understand there is a missing `from`, but the old-style join with the specification in the `where` is what I was referencing. If you add a `from` to that statement it becomes an old-style join query.

Answer (score 3):

This is the exact definition of a `left join`:

```
SELECT    a.id, b.name, b.path, c.file
FROM      a
JOIN      b ON a.id = b.id 
LEFT JOIN c ON b.subid = c.subid
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `LEFT JOIN` your third table from what I can gather.

```
SELECT A.Id, A.Name, B.Path, C.file
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b ON a.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN tableC c ON b.subid = c.subid
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Join all the three tables using INNER JOIN

```
select A.Id, A.Name, B.Path ,C.File
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.Id=B.Id 
INNER JOIN C
ON C.SubId=B.SubId
```